# стиль списка wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Необходимо прописать стиль для нумерованного списка в wordpress, я понимаю, что это просто, делала раньше, но вот в конкретной теме возникли проблемы.
Отступы нужны у всего текста, а не только у первой строки (как сейчас). Скину ссылку на страницу со списком http://www.ortoped-bodyo.ru/patsientam/ и то, что должно получится [image: result]

Answer (score 2):

```css
.num-list {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.num-list_item { margin: 0 0 10px; }

.num-list_item:before {
  content: counter(item) '.';
  counter-increment: item;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: #0095e5;
}

.num-list_item:nth-child(n+10):before { margin-right: 95px; }
```

```html
<ol class="num-list">
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li class="num-list_item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  text-indent: -36px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  text-align: left;
}

li span {
  color: #0095e5;
}
```

```html
<li><span>07.</span> Ходьба по гимнастической палке (палка от швабры). Палка лежит перпендикулярно движению, начинаем наступать на неё пальцами и очень мелкими шагами продвигаемся вперёд, доходя до конца пяток. Пройти нужно как вперёд, так и назад, 4-5 раз.
  Движения должны быть медленными, необходимо задействовать каждый сантиметр подошвы.</li>
<li><span>08.</span> Продвижение себя вперёд-назад используя только пальцы стоп. Упражнение выполняется стоя. Движение будет напоминать движение гусеницы. 20-30 см вперёд и назад. Повторить 2-3 раза.</li>
```

На элементы `<li>` надо поставить

```
element.style {
    text-indent: -42px;
    margin-left: 42px;
    color: black;
}
```

А цифры в начале абзаца обернуть в `span`, для которого указать свой цвет.

В примере кода шрифт другой, потому выравнивание не очень. 42px - это для вашего шрифта Roboto 20.